# Sequelize: Where should these methods reside

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

You have 2 tables:

- Users
- Accounts

A user can have many accounts.

You need to add an account to a user. Using Sequelize, you can attach an instance method to the User model called addAccount(). But also, if you look at it from a different angle, the Account table is really creating a new record, so the Account model could have a class method called createAccount().

Which is more semantically correct? Or should the solution be a mix of both where you call addAccount() on a user instance and that method calls the class method createAccount() on the Account model?

And considering that this is a node/express app, the information to create the account needs to be validated and then parsed from the request. Where would you make that validation/parsing happen? In the routes before calling the account creation method? Or as a 'private' function (__parseReq) in the class methods of either the User model or the Account model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were in your position, I would prefer to use `addAccount` on a user instance. The main reason is because by doing so, you can easily say that the newly created account "belongs to" the user instance in question.

Anyway, if (for some reasons) you really need to create an individual account without the presence of a user instance, you can still use `Account.create()`.

For the value validation, you could either manually validate before doing sequelize operations or you could define your validation rules in the model definition (more info [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#validations)).